# Primefaces p:printer loses all custom css

Tags: css, primefaces, printing

I have a dialog with some text in rows and columns, im using css to remove the borders of the panel/rows in the dialog box. however when I use  with the target set as my dialog box it displaces everything in the dialog box but with all the borders showing and none of my custom css.

Is there a way of telling the printer to use the custom css or stop it going back to the default?

Comment: In my case I'm losing all `@media print` I have configured such as `page-break`

Answer (score 1):

I still can't figure out why the printer is ignoring the CSS but I have found a work around.

By adding ***border:none;*** to each row and column in my dialog it works

```
<p:row styleClass=".ui-panelgrid" border= "0" style="border: none;">
                <p:column colspan="3" border= "0" style="border: none;">
```

hope this is useful for someone in the future, but if anyone would care to explain why the  was ignoring the custom CSS in the first place I would love to know. thanks